# Pandas rolling window rank order with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, rolling-computation

I supposed I have Pandas DataFrame look like below:

```
  account   amount  
  A         10      
  A         10      
  A         20      
  A         10      
  A         10      
  A         10      
  B         10      
  B         10      
  B         20      
  B         18      
  B         18      
  B         12      
  B         14      
  B         18      
  B         19
```

I want a new column look like below:

```
  account   want  
  A         nan   
  A         nan   
  A         1     
  A         2     
  A         3     
  A         1     
  B         nan   
  B         nan   
  B         1     
  B         2     
  B         3     
  B         1     
  B         2     
  B         1     
  B         1
```

The idea is to rank order (starting with 1) after maximum value found in the given window.

For example, the given window is `3`, in the account `A`, the maximum amount is `20`. Then, index `2` will return `1` since `20` is the maximum value in given window. After that for the next rolling window, at index `3` will return `2` since the amount is `10` which is less than `20` from above.

Applied the logic to account `B`, the results as shown. I could think about create the maximum of amount rolling window with 3 but I cannot do further.

Comment: What is the logic behind:   `A         3 `  in the output? Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: At index 4, the amount is 10 compared to maximum amount in the past 3 window, which is 20. Then, it ranks from 20 as 3 (starting with 1). [20, 10, 10] = [1, 2, 3]

Comment: Can you explain further how your rolling window works? Shouldn't the value at index 2 be 20 and also at index 3 20 again?

Comment: Basically, I want to rank order after maximum value found in the rolling window. Consider the first window [10, 10, 20], the maximum value is 20 at index 2, value return 1. Consider the second window [10, 20, 10] the maximum value still 20 but the index changed to 1, amount at index 3 is 10, compared to maximum is 20. Then, it will rank from index contained 20 and return as 2

Comment: Following the same logic how is that the two last values for group A are 3 and 1? I understand the 3, but not the 1.

Comment: 3 is because [20, 10, 10] ranked as [1, 2, 3]. 1 is because the rolling window is [10, 10, 10], the amount at index 5 is 10 and equal to maximum rolling window then it returns 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226377/discussion-between-dani-mesejo-and-sasiwut-chaiyadecha).

Answer (score 0):

I think I could solve this issue by code below:

```
def rank(window):
    newWindow = np.array(window)
    lastMax = np.where(newWindow == np.amax(newWindow))[0][-1]
    maxLocation = np.repeat(lastMax, newWindow.shape[0])
    location = np.arange(0, newWindow.shape[0])    
    ranks = location - maxLocation + 1
    return ranks[-1]

df['want'] = df.groupby('account')['amount'].rolling(window = 3).apply(rank).droplevel(0)
```

Thanks, every one!